# Rescue from Errno::ECONNRESET when running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, bundler

I'm working on a gem to scaffold a new Rails app with a variety of dependencies. When running `bundle install`, I periodically hit this error:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/gems/<gem_name>.gem)
An error occurred while installing <gem_name> (x.x.x), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install <gem_name> -v 'x.x.x'` succeeds before bundling.
```

If I just new up a Rails app and hit this, the error is easily remedied by running `bundle install` a few times until everything installs without failure, however, in the generator gem, I need to be able to catch this error and retry `bundle install`. I would expect something along the lines of this to work, but it doesn't:

```
begin
  run 'bundle install'
rescue Errno::ECONNRESET => e
  puts "Retrying... Error caught: #{e}"
  count += 1
  retry unless count > 10
  puts "Tried to `bundle install` 10 times: #{e}"
end
```

Help?

Comment: You cannot catch an exception that is happing in a completely different process. Usually you invoke a process and check the exit code - in this case it sounds like a fools errand through since the root problem is that you have a spotty network connection and should be addressing that instead.

Comment: Also, the error is wrapped inside a `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError` I think `"Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection ..."` is just the message inside the other error. But I agree with the commenter above, this is probably better left for the developer to fix.